# google play maximum number of (free) apps per accountº

Tags: android, google-play

I have bought a license (account) to develop free Android apps. Is there any limitation to the number of apps I can upload?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would there be a limit? The good thing about Android is that releasing apps is quick and painless. Personally I have just released a single app so far, so I doubt I will get close to the limit any time soon (assuming there is one) ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked this very question during a Hangout with the guys from Google. They said they weren't aware of any limit.

My company has going on for nearly 300 apps now.