# How many apps can be published in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing android applications. I haven't created a publisher account yet.
I want to publish my own created android apps in Google Play. There is fees of 25$. How many apps I can publish from my account? Is this one time fees (25$) or may I have to pay again in the future for this account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google play maximum number of (free) apps per accountº](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389963/google-play-maximum-number-of-free-apps-per-account)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unlimited**

This is a one-time fee (25$).

Answer (score 2):

you can publish as many apps you want with one account & the One-Time-Fee

Answer (score 0):

As many as you want, and Google doesn't test or really regulate what you put on the market. So if it's a half-broken demo you can still post it.